How to Thoroughly Test PrimeReact AutoComplete Component with API Handling and Virtual Scrolling in React?
I’m working on a project using PrimeReact’s AutoComplete component to search customers by different criteria (e.g., name, mobile number, etc.). The search suggestions are fetched from an API, and the component is set up with various event handlers for onSearch, onSelect, and onClear events.
Jest and react testing library
Here’s a simplified version of our AutoComplete component implementation:
<AutoComplete
 placeholder={`Search Customer By ${searchCriteria}`}
 inputClassName='customer-search-bar__autocomplete w-full'
 className='w-5'
 field={searchCriteria}
 value={searchValue}
 suggestions={suggestions}
 itemTemplate={(item) => <CustomerInfo {...item} />}
 virtualScrollerOptions={{ itemSize: 100 }}
 completeMethod={onSearch}
 onSelect={onCustomerSelect}
 onClear={onClear}
/>

